# Determine whether or not a linear transformation is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

i am considering a number of linear transformations that look like the one below.

$T:R^2 \mapsto R^3, T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1-2a_2,a_2,3a_1+4a_2)$

i want to say that $T$ isn't invertible because $rank(T)=3\neq dim(V)=2$.

i.e., since the domain and codomain have different dimensions, $T$ isn't invertible.

is this enough?

Comment: Yes, it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct, but not the computations. What happens is that$$\operatorname{rank}T=2\neq\dim\mathbb R^3=3.$$More generally, no linear map $f$ from a vector space with dimension $n$ into a vector space $V$ with dimension $m>n$ can be impossible, since$$\operatorname{rank}f\leqslant n<m=\dim V.$$

Comment: thank you. would another acceptable way to answer this be that since $dim(R^2) \neq dim(R^3)$, T isn't invertible?

Comment: Yes, that would work too.

Comment: More basic would be to try to find an inverse.  Given x, y, z, try to find a, b such that T(a, b)= (a- 2b, b. 3a+ 4b)= (x, y, z).

Comment: More fundamental would be to try to find an inverse.  Given x, y, z, try to find a, b such that T(a, b)= (a- 2b, b. 3a+ 4b)= (x, y, z).  Obviously, b= y.  Then a- 2b= a- 2y= x so a= x+ 2y.  And then 3a+ 4b= 3x+ 6y+ 4y= 3x+ 10y= z which is not, in general true.  You could use that to construct a counter-example.  Take x= y= z= 1 so it is NOT true that 3x+ 10y= z.  There are no a, b such that T(a, b)= (a- 2b, b, 3a+ 4b)= (1, 1, 1).  That would require that b= 1 so that a- 2b= a- 2= 1 so a= 3.  But then 3a+ 4b= 9+ 4= 13, not 1.